# Chef Bootsrapping SSL error for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, chef-infra

I am new to chef and I've been trying to bootstrap Windows Server 2008 R2. I have Chef 12 installed and when i try to bootstrap windows node i get this error. "**ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: 10.XXX.XX.XX returned=1 errno=0 state=sslv3 read server certificate b: certificate verify failed**". I've researched everything online and done everything to fix this error but I could not solve this issue. Anyone who has experience bootstrapping windows server, please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting

```
ssl_verify_mode :verify_none
```

into the node's client.rb file helps, but I'm not sure if there's a way yet to write that to the file during the bootstrap. Still searching for that.

Comment: Yea i've been looking at this problem for while now.